# Reading all lines from a HttpRequestedFileBase

Tags: c#, httprequest, file.readalllines, filecontentresult

i'm fetching a file by **HttpRequestedFileBase**, txt type, and I need to read each line in the file and store those line in variables to workin with them. But I'm wondering if i should convert the file to read it. Also I get some errors whiles I was trying to implement the read.

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
string value = Request.Form["objectList"].ToString();
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
string banc = form["objectlistbanc"].ToString();

var lix = file.InputStream; //not sure if inputsteam is what i need

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lix); // error here says i need a fileContenResult using file content and file type
foreach (var line in lines) {
  string ln = line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to convert the stream to read it.

But you can simply call this method to read the content of the file.

```
 string content = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

or to read line by line

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream)) 
{ 
   while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
   { 
      var line = reader.ReadLine(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: ok so I tried this with a for each but it's reading every single caracter from the row and i would like to catch a row for each read, 

is there any way to do something like that

Comment: using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

Comment: Error says 'invalid' characters D:

Comment: > System.ArgumentException: invalid characters in the "path".
> string content = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();


                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var line = reader.ReadLine();
                            Extraer(line);
                        }
                    }

Comment: But need those caracters in my file name it's a ' ' blanck space what's getting me in trouble

Comment: can't answer, it convention .net

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim  finally, you resolve your problem?. Don't forget to mark the answer if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: well, yes I solved but I'm not using your method, at the end I didi this:
> string content = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();               
for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
{
    var a = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\n", i));
    Extraer(a);
    content = content.Remove(0, content.IndexOf("\n", i));
}
 
would you give me any advice?